# Gaussian mixture models for image matrix not determining E step

Tags: machine-learning, probability, python, gaussian-mixture-distribution, numpy

I want to calculate responsibility for each of the data points, for the given MU, SIGMA and PI.

```
params:
 X = numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]] - m x n
 MU = numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]] - k x n
 SIGMA = numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]]] - k x n x n
 PI = numpy.ndarray[float] - k x 1
 k = int

returns:
responsibility = numpy.ndarray[numpy.ndarray[float]] - k x m
```

I tried doing

```
for i in range(k):
        part1 = 1 / ( ((2* np.pi)**(len(MU[i])/2)) * (np.linalg.det(SIGMA[i])**(1/2)) )
        print(X-MU[i], np.linalg.inv(SIGMA[i]))
        part2 = np.exp((-1/2) * ((X-MU[i]).T.dot(np.linalg.inv(SIGMA[i]))).dot((X-MU[i])))
        weighted_normal = PI[i] * part1 * part2
```

The above code seems to work for each entry of X which is matrix of m x n. So it calculates the probability correctly for one entry in x. How to get it for all the values of X simultaneously. Iterating over each value is slower.